# How exactly does one 'introduce nilpotents' to a scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For context, I am trying to understand the counterexample credited to Kleiman, which proves that the natural map $\operatorname{Div}(X) \to \operatorname{Pic}(X)$ is not in general surjective, where the domain is the set of Cartier divisors. The explanation in Lazarsfeld's "Positivity I" page 11 has the following:

> ... now introduce nilpotents at $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ to produce a non-reduced scheme $X$ containing $Y$ as a closed subscheme.

I'm not really sure how one would do this, so I found this [other source](http://martapr.webs.uvigo.es/Investigacion/Divisors.pdf) which constructs $X$ by keeping the underlying topological space the same, but changing the structure sheaf to ensure that the stalks at $a$ and $b$ are $\mathcal{O}_{Y, a} \ltimes k(a)$  and $\mathcal{O}_{Y, b} \ltimes k(b)$, which they describe as the 'semidirect product'.

Now, I have never heard of a semidirect product of commutative rings, and I haven't been able to find an explanation of what this means, let alone how one constructs a sheaf of rings to ensure this property.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me interpret this 'semidirect product' or explain how one introduces nilpotents to a certain point of a scheme like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Affine-locally, you can describe this as the spectrum of the ring $R\times k(a)$ with addition $(r,c)+(r',c')=(r+r',c+c')$ and multiplication $(r,c)\cdot(r',c')=(rr',\overline{r}c'+\overline{r'}c)$ where $\overline{-}$ denotes the image of $r$ in $k(a)$. Equivalently, this ring is $R[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2,\varepsilon\cdot \mathfrak{m}_a)$.

Considering the example of $k[t]$ and $(t)$, we get $k[t,u]/(tu,u^2)$, which is exactly the affine line with some fuzz at the origin.

Comment: This is much clearer; thank you. In this case, $a$ will be the only closed point where the local ring has nilpotents, right? So that the reduced locus is $X \setminus \{a\}$.

Comment: Assuming your original scheme is reduced, yes - as soon as any element in $\mathfrak{a}$ is invertible you have $\varepsilon=0$ at that point. (Alternatively, there's an isomorphism of structure sheaves away from $a$...)